# View document link in salesforce using DocuSign Apex toolkit

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect, docusignapextoolkit

We are using Docusign Apex toolkit in Salesforce. We create an envelope in draft Status.
Can we view the envelope in draft status in Salesofrce using a link by document id.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to view the draft envelope by Apextoolkit. Or maybe not directly from Apextoolkit.

I would like to suggest the following:

1-GetSenderViewUrl method documented here: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/salesforce/apex-toolkit-reference/envelopeservice.html

2-Or You can view the envelope through SenderView but it is only available with the eSignature RestAPI.

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/createsender/
Returns a URL to the sender view UI.

I hope the information shared works.